# Is John 1:11 an antithetical parallel to Deut. 33.3?

Tags: john, jesus, typology

John 1:14,17 draw parallels between Moses receiving the Law and Jesus.
(See [In John 1:14 what does ἐσκήνωσεν mean?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/58806/in-john-114-what-does-%E1%BC%90%CF%83%CE%BA%CE%AE%CE%BD%CF%89%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%BD-mean))

```
        Yes, he loved his people, 
  all his holy ones were in his hand; 
              so they followed in your steps, 
  receiving direction from you, 
                 (Deut. 33:3, ESV)
```

Deut. 33:3 references his people receiving the Law.  John 1:11 references his people not receiving Christ.

> He came to his own, and his own people did not receive him.
> (John 1:11, ESV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deuteronomy 33:

> 3 Yes, he loved **his people**,
> all his holy ones were in his hand;
> so they followed in your steps,
> **receiving** direction from you,

John 1:

> 11
> He came to his own,
> and his own people did **not receive** him.

In terms of forms, the two verses look quite different. They don't look parallel.

Is John 1:11 an antithetical parallel to Deut. 33.3?

Perhaps not formally parallel but they are antithetical: "receiving" as opposed to "not receive".

Deuteronomy 33:3 was part of Moses’ final blessing on Israel before he died.
Despite this antithetical element, Deuteronomy 33:3's blessing was fulfilled in John 1:

> 12 But to all who **did receive** him, who believed in his name, he gave the right to become children of God, 13 who were born, not of blood nor of the will of the flesh nor of the will of man, but of God.

Now the definition of "his people" in Deuteronomy 33:3 was expanded to include the Gentiles who received and believed Jesus.

OP: Deut. 33:3 references his people receiving the Law. John 1:11 references his people not receiving Christ.

Right. However, the very next verse, John 1:12, references his people receiving Christ.